# How can I get outlook to do emacs bindings?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, emacs, key-binding

I'm not even  sure that this is possible. However, here goes.

I am a follower of the true church of Emacs. My fingers know the key bindings, and they just do stuff. Normally this is great. The problem comes when I'm writing an email in outlook, and say, I need to add a new-line one line up. C-p return. *OOPS I just printed the page*

So, is this even possible? (I'm forced to use Outlook at my company, so email readers within emacs aren't an option)

Answer (score 3):

Look into [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/).  Its all the rage with people trying to make their typing more efficient.

Comment: Does that mean you manually have to create all emacs bindings there?